# MURA website login form customisations

Tags: coldfusion, mura

Im currently looking into the MURA cms. and while it looks quite nice. I cant seem to alter something that appears to be quite trivial on other platforms.

Im simply wanting to know the location of where the base login form template resides whether it be in a JS file or as a simple .cfm template.

Any ideas greatly apprecated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite/customise the display object that renders the login form.

Take a look at the following documentation on how to:
http://docs.getmura.com/v6/front-end/customizations-staying-on-the-upgrade-path/customizing-display-objects/

And this is the file you want to modify:
https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/blob/develop/default/includes/display_objects/dsp_login.cfm

Comment: thanks for the pointer, now I can see where the dsp files are located it makes it much easier to navigate around the Mura platform.